# Infragistics WinGrid: How to make a CheckBox column initially checked

Tags: c#, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid, wingrid

I have an Infragistics WinGrid (UltraGrid, UltraWinGrid, whatever...) with an unbound column. It has `Style = Checkbox` and `DataType = System.Boolean`. I have set `DefaultCellValue` to `true`, but every new row appears with `cell.Value == False` in that column. How can I get the default value to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails I would suggest you revert to setting the value manually on the `InitializeRow` event.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `yourColumn.DataType = typeof(bool)` and `yourColumn.DefaultCellValue = true`.

Comment: The DefaultCellValue applies to rows added via the add row feature and will not affect the rows from the data source.  This is in the documentation here: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~DefaultCellValue.html

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a old post, but this might help someone googling the answer!

On new rows, you can use the InitializeTemplateAddRow event, from there you can set the value of the desired column

```
//Add TemplateAddRow handler
_ultraGrid.InitializeTemplateAddRow += _ultraGrid_InitializeTemplateAddRow

//In the InitializeTemplateAddRow set the cells value
e.TemplateAddRow.Cells[CELLNAME].Value = true;
//OR
e.TemplateAddRow.Cells[index].Value = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

When possible I like to use my own view model class when I bind to the grid and so when I encounter this problem I just add the needed column with a default of true.

If you cannot use your own view model class you can also handle the grid's Initialize event and set it there.